# remote: Permission to *****newuser.git denied to *****1stusername

Tags: github, git-push, git-remote

**in Visual studio code**

i spent a lot more time for this, I'm trying push **my deleted project that is coming from 1st account github** into  **an existing repository in new another account**, but I'm getting error like this :

```
$ git push -u origin main
remote: Permission to username/project_name.git denied to first_account_username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user_name/project_name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

i tried those command line for push an existing repository in new account, please let me know what'd i miss ?

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user_name/project_name.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: This problem is not related to VS code, gitlab or pull requests. Please remove the according tags and the information about it in the question. Instead, add the `git` tag.

Answer (score 11):

Git obviously tries to push code to your new repository using your old username. Add you new username explicitly to the URL:

```
git remote set-url origin https://user_name@github.com/user_name/project_name.git
```

Or use the [SSH syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#about-remote-repositories):

```
git remote set-url origin user_name@github.com:user_name/project_name.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Just see the same problem and here is my solution:
Before we generate the token. We need to enable some elements of "**select scopes** in github settings as show below.
[image]

I just select several elements and generate key. Therefore I can push the code after fill username and password(**generated key**).

Answer (score 1):

First check your credentials:

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

Then change with:

```
git config --global user.name "email"
git config --global user.email "email@email.com"
```

If you set another credential before, will have problem
use `git config credential.username "username"`

Answer (score 0):

**Question :**

$ git push -u origin main

remote: Permission to username/project_name.git denied to another_username

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user_name/project_name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

**Answer :**

1. Above the Setting icon in visual studio code there will be a Account Sign in logo icon, click and check it is login with another account or not ?
2. If it is log in with another Account you will be get the same error continuously... So,
3. ***The solution is*** : You should **sign out the other Account in the visual studio**  and then try in visual studio code terminal following code given below...

$ **git push**

4. Then it will ask **username and password**
   you should enter the correct details and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check what configuration helper you do have: it might have cached the wrong credentials (from the old users).

```
git config --global credential helper
```

Adjust you PATH to use said credential helper.

If you are on Windows, in a CMD, set a simplified `PATH` like:

```bash
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=%ProgramFiles%\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Then type in the same CMD:

```
 printf "Host=bitbucket.org\nprotocol=https\nusername=old_username" | git credential-manager-core erase
```

Replace:

- `manager-core` by your actual credential helper, as returned by `git config --global credential helper`
- `old_username` by the old username GitHub account

Then try again.